# Error when more than one fight in same channel

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make a fight command in discord.js v13
So how this code works is
Every time a **select_menu** is selected,
It runs the collector and loops over 'collect' event till the health one of the players zero.
It works fine if there is only one fight going on in the channel,but when someone uses fight command when there is a fight command going on in the same channel, It throws

throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
^

DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged.

```
const collector1 = await interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, componentType: 'SELECT_MENU', time: 600000 })
collector1.on('collect', async i => {
if (//my condition){
//action 
collector1
}
Thank you any help would be appreciated!
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to see more of your code (specifically, your filter declaration), but that is where the problem seems to be. Make sure your filter is only looking at the user who started the interaction:

```
const filter = (i) => (i.user.id === interaction.user.id);
```

Additionally, make sure your collector is running multiple times (it would help if you post your entire `interactionCreate` function.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a collect for an entire channel, this causes other messages to also detect these interactions, hence the error.

If the interaction returns a reply you need to fetch the reply of the interaction:

```js
/*...*/
const reply = await interaction.fetchReply();
const collector1 = await reply.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, componentType: 'SELECT_MENU', time: 600000 });
/*...*/
```

If it returns a message you need to save it in a variable:

```js
/*...*/
const msg = await interaction.channel.send(...);
msg.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, componentType: 'SELECT_MENU', time: 600000 })
/*...*/
```

This might help you...

(Sorry if my English is bad, I used google translate in most of this message)